# Get the byte array of file in repository

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

Is it possible to get the byte array of a file from repository using SharpSVN?

I have a file which I put into a repo but for security I want to compute the MD5 before and after upload. To achieve it i must have byte array of file.

Comment: I guess you didn't search before asking? First google result [sharpsvn get file]: http://sharpsvntips.net/post/45301798139/getting-file-content-from-repository-in-memory